# Question about the Dynamic Dictionary feature of the Microsoft Translator API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

I am currently testing the Microsoft Translator API and its individual API functions. I have already read through the documentation on the Dynamic Dictionary feature (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/translator/dynamic-dictionary) but I am still unsure about its practical application. My interpretation is that it allows me to specify for an English word how it should be rendered in another language - and vice versa. Below is a sketch of my current interpretation:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGQcY.png) Am I correct in this assumption?

I have read the documentation completely and i don't understand how to specify that it is recognized that i have to replace the word from english to french now, and from english to spanish next time...). I have already implemented other features of the API, there the documentation was clearer.

Comment: you have to provide the "translation" you want for the term. So in your en->fr request, you would provide the French target, and in you en->es you provide the Spanish target. You don't provide both at the same time, so there is no picking.

Answer (score 1):

The Dynamic Dictionary in the Microsoft Translator API allows you to customize translations for specific terms or phrases, not limited to English-to-French or English-to-Spanish. You define custom translations based on context, languages, or situations, ensuring precise translations for your specific needs. It's a valuable tool for maintaining consistency and accuracy in translations across various contexts and languages.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please show me how to enter the code for the example in the photo? With an example it would be easier for me to understand.